# How to fix Play Store error about 64 bit binaries when publishing app built Expo / React Native?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am deploying an app built with React Native and Expo to Play Store and the following error appears:

> This release is not compliant with the Play 64-bit requirement.
>   The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they have only 32-bit native code: 1. From 1 de agosto de 2019 all releases must be compliant with the Play 64-bit requirement.Include 64-bit native code in addition to 32-bit native code in your app. Use the Android App Bundle publishing format to automatically ensure that each device architecture receives just the native code it needs.

My Expo version is 27.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On July 16th 2019 they stated in [64-Bit Support and Android App Bundles](https://blog.expo.io/64-bit-support-and-android-app-bundles-fe0c6a28669):

> We want to let you know that you can now build 64-bit support-enabled .apks that also make use of Android App Bundles (AABs) with SDK33 projects and, of course, with SDK34 upon its release. (Since SDK33 is the first Expo SDK version that uses React Native 0.59, the React Native version that allows for 64-bit support, prior versions of the SDK can’t be updated.)
>
> These updates help us support your new submissions to the Google Play store, which will need to have 64-bit support starting August 1st. Your existing apps won’t need to upgrade to include 64-bit until you need to submit your next app update (though SDK33 has a lot of other fun things you might enjoy!).
>
> Ensure you are running the latest version of `expo-cli` by running `yarn global add expo-cli` or `npm install -g expo-cli`.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding this post https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2814 react-native v0.59 is 64bit compliant (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2019/03/12/releasing-react-native-059)

and Expo 27 support react-native v0.55.
I'm not an expert with Expo, but can you manually upgrade react-native to v0.59 ? or maybe wait a new version of Expo ?

Comment: as I posted in my answer, waiting for a new version seems to be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no way to fix this. But the Expo Team promised ...

> ... to add this feature *[64-bit binaries]* before the deadline.

see here: https://forums.expo.io/t/does-expo-package-64-bit-version/18947